# codeigniter routing with variable segment

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2

I've been reading the codeigniter manual about routing but I don't understand how to apply the feature to my situation.

I'm trying to design the following URI

```
example.com/shopName/product/2/description
example.com/shopName/product/2/gallery
```

Where shopName is the name of the shop (ie. different every time).=

I'm in the beginning of the project so my controllers are open to alterations.
I've been thinking of doing something like the structure below, as a workaround, but it is definitely not what would be ideal.

```
example.com/shop/pdesc/2 
example.com/shop/pgallery/2
```

Comment: Your first choice seems good I think.

Comment: @RajuDawadi well that is the standard way of doing it. My question is how to achieve the URIs at the top.

Answer (score 0):

First change route like this:

```
 $route['shopName/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'shopname/$1/$2/$3';
```

You may change this as per your design.
Then create controllers. Read this guide for details. [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

Comment: Quote OP: *"Where `shopName` is the name of the shop (ie. **different every time**)"*